# To-Many Core Data sync with parse.com

Tags: ios, core-data, parse-platform, ftasync

I'm using FTASync to sync Core Data with Parse.

Does anyone know how to set up To-Many relationships with FTASync and the Parse SDK? If so, could you point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Comment: +1. FTASync is very low on users / contributors at the minute and I'm having issues with its robustness when it comes to my own data models. The sample project works fine!